# Perl regex using negative look? can't seem to figure out how to do this properly

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to get this to work with perl's regex but can't seem to figure it out.. I want to grab any url that has ".website." in it, except ones that are like this (with "en" preceding ".website."

```
   $linkhtml =  'http://en.search.website.com/?q=beach&' ;
```

This is an example of a url that I would want to be returned by the regex, while the one above is rejected

```
   $linkhtml =  ' http://exsample.website.com/?q=beach&' ;
```

Here is my attempt at it.. any advice on what I'm doing wrong is appreciated

```
   $re2='(?<!en)'; # Any number of characters
   $re4='(.*)'; # Any number of characters
   $re6='(\.)'; # Any Single Character 4
   $re7='(website)'; # Word 2
   $re8='(\.)'; # Any Single Character 5
   $re9='(.*)'; # Any number of characters

   $re=$re4.$re2.$re6.$re7.$re8.$re9;

   if ($linkhtml =~ /$re/)
```

Comment: Well the examples you gave won't match because your URLs contain "website.com" and you are looking for "wordpress"... Can you post the actual patterns and strings you were using?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I edited the original post

Comment: well, I took a script output by this "http://www.txt2re.com/index.php3?s=29:Mar:2008%20%22This%20is%20an%20Example!%22&10" and am editing it so thats why I ended up with numbers out of order since I did a number of edits on the original output from that

Comment: As you have it, it will only catch an `en` directly before the `.website` because you have `$re2.$re6.$re7`. That's why it doesnt catch your first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative lookbehind assertions don't work well if the content you are trying to match *after* the assertion is so general that it would match the assertion itself.  Consider:

```
perl -wle'print "en.website" =~ qr/(?<!en\.)web/'        # doesn't match
perl -wle'print "en.website" =~ qr/(?<!en\.)[a-z]/'      # does match, because [a-z] is matching the 'en'
```

The best thing to do here is what David suggested: use two patterns to screen out the good and bad values:

```
my @matches = grep {
     /$pattern1/ and not /$pattern2/
} @strings;
```

...where pattern1 matches all URLs, and pattern2 matches just the 'en' URLs.

Comment: I edited the original post to take out the http.. I don't need to match that as any string I input is already a link so it was superfluous.. I understand what you mean, though, so I will try to adapt this to my need as I need to discard any url that has the "en" in it and then match any remaining url that has "website" in it

Comment: @Rick: PS. [Regexp::Common::URI::http](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp::Common::URI::http) might be of use to you too...

Comment: Where do you see an overly generic expression after a lookbehind?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do it in two steps: first use a generic regular expression to check for any URL (or rather, anything that looks like a URL). Then check each result that matches that against another regex that looks for `en` occurring in the host before `wordpress`, and discard anything that matches.

Comment: Actually I already know its a URL as I am using mechanize to extract all links, so the $re3='(http)'; part is unecessary.. I'm having trouble with the part I described in the initial post of matching the negative "en"

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final solution, in case anyone comes across this in the future that is new to regex (as I am) and has a similar problem.. in my case I wrapped this is a "for loop" so it would go through an array but it just depends on the need.

#### first lets filter out the urls that have "en" as these aren't urls we want

```
        $re1='(.*)';    # Any number of characters
        $re2='(en)';    # Word 1
        $re3='(.*)'; # Any number of characters


        $re=$re1.$re2.$re3;
        if ($linkhtml =~ /$re/)
        {


    #do nothing, as we don't want a link with "en" in it

        }

        else {

        ### find urls with ".website."
        $re1='(.*)';    # Any number of characters
        $re2='(\.)';    # period
        $re3='(website)';   # Word 1
        $re4='(\.)';    # period
        $re5='(.*)'; # Any number of characters


        $re=$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5;

            if ($linkhtml =~ /$re/) {

            #match to see if it is a link that has ".website." in it


            ## do something with the data as it matches, such as:
                       print "linkhtml

            }

           }
```

Comment: You blocked my homepage, www.website.com/benspage.html :(